# Rotate Outgoing Ip in Postfix, script not working

Tags: bash, shell-script, postfix

I've found what it seems to be a nice piece of code meant to rotate postfix IP but I really can't get it to work. when I run it I get this error:

```
rotate_postfix_ip.sh: 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I have no idea how to fix it, could anyone help me please?

```
#!/bin/bash
ips=("64.250.120.128" "64.250.121.241" "64.250.121.242")
length=${#ips[@]}
pos=`cat current.txt`
oldip=${ips[$pos - 1]}
if [ "$length" -eq "$pos" ] ; then
    echo "limit reached"
    pos=1
else
    echo "increment!"
    (( pos++ ))
fi

echo "$pos" > current.txt

newip=${ips[$pos - 1]}
echo "prev: $oldip"
echo "new: $newip"

sed -ie "s/smtp_bind_address=$oldip/smtp_bind_address=$newip/g" /etc/postfix/main.cf > /dev/null
service postfix reload






x@debi:~$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
ips=("1" "2" "3")

x@debi:~$ sh test.sh
test.sh: 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
x@debi:~$ bash -xv test.sh
#!/bin/bash
ips=("1" "2" "3")
+ ips=("1" "2" "3")
```

damn, it's not something with the new line endings. I've edited a new file with vim and it yields the same error.

Comment: What `bash` version are you using? Works fine with `GNU bash, version 4.1.10(4)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)`.

Comment: Try to insert `declare -a ips` after the shebang line.

Comment: @mpy GNU bash,    version 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu), also tried with the declare -a and it still didn't work

Comment: No messed up line endings, i.e. \n\r instead of \n? Probably `bash -xv rotate_postfix_ip.sh`won't give any new hints? Also please try entering `ips=("64.250.120.128" "64.250.121.241" "64.250.121.242")` at the (bash-) command line.

Comment: How do you execute the script? If you do `sh /path/to/rotate_postfix_ip.sh` it ***won't*** run, because `bash`, when invoked as `sh`, mimics the Bourne shell, which doesn't support arrays. You must run the script either like this: `bash /path/to/rotate_postfix_ip.sh` or like this: `chmod 755 /path/to/rotate_postfix_ip.sh; /path/to/rotate_postfix_ip.sh`.

Comment: ^ this is the correct answer, if you want to add it I'll gladly mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Run the script with "bash" command. it would solve the problem,

for example : `bash rotate_postfix_ip.sh`

Answer (score 1):

That's why I always prefer portable POSIX solutions that always works...

```
#!/bin/sh

ips='
    64.250.120.128

    64.250.121.241
    64.250.121.242
'
#####################################################
[ ! -f './current.txt' ] && echo '1' > ./current.txt

nIPS=0
for ip in ${ips}; do nIPS=$(( nIPS + 1 )); done

pos=$(cat ./current.txt)
counter=1
for oldip in ${ips}; do
    [ $pos -eq $counter ] && break
    counter=$(( counter + 1 ))
done

[ "$nIPS" -eq "$pos" ] && {
    echo "limit reached"
    pos=1
} || {
    echo "increment!"
    pos=$(( pos + 1 ))
}

echo "$pos"  > current.txt

counter=1
for newip in ${ips};do
    [ $pos -eq $counter ] && break
    counter=$(( counter + 1 ))
done

echo "prev: $oldip"
echo "new: $newip"

sed -ie "s/smtp_bind_address=$oldip/smtp_bind_address=$newip/g" /etc/postfix/main.cf > /dev/null
service postfix reload
```